# PowerMock @SuppressStaticInitializationFor doesn't work for nested class inside the test class

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock, powermockito

I made a change to a widely-used base class in our codebase, adding a static initialization block. I'm now going through all of our unit tests, trying to make them work by adding

```
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("com.mycompany.WidelyUsedBaseClass")
```

This is working in some cases, but I can't get it to work with test classes that have an inner class which extends the `WidelyUsedBaseClass`. (Don't ask me why these nested classes exist; I'm not sure why a standard mock wouldn't suffice. Anyway, I don't want to try to refactor this because I'm not fully confident I understand the test logic using these inner classes.)

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("com.mycompany.WidelyUsedBaseClass") // <-- This isn't working! I can still see <clinit> in the exception when the test fails...
public class SomeTestsFromAnotherTeam
{
    // test logic...
    // more test logic...
    Stub myStub = new Stub();
    // more test logic...

    private class Stub extends WidelyUsedBaseClass
    {
        // some other logic...
    }
}
```

I think the problem is occurring at the `new Stub()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wasn't able to figure out exactly what's going on, but I did find a way around the problem.

The tests pass after moving the inner class outside of the enclosing class. I just put it after the `SomeTestsFromAnotherTeam` class in the same file and made it package private:

```
public class SomeTestsFromAnotherTeam
{
    // ...
}

class Stub extends WidelyUsedBaseClass
{
    // ...
}
```